# Unable to addReactInstanceEventListener to React InstanceManager

Tags: java, react-android

I am trying to use a fix from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3887#issuecomment-332299138), but when using the solution in my code, `this` is not available. How can I pass `this` to the function?

´´´java

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "fleeting";
    }

    private ReactContext mReactContext;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock sCpuWakeLock;
    private Activity activity;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Here's your valid ReactContext");
        mReactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getReactInstanceManager().addReactInstanceEventListener(this); // Throws error, can´t find "this"
```

Comment: The issue says you need to implement `ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener`, are you?

Comment: No, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Can you provide the _exact error text_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace you first line with below code. You were not implemented the **ReactInstanceEventListener** interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity  implements ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener{
```

Then add this method inside your mainActivity.

```
@Override
public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Here's your valid ReactContext");
}
```